# why would load_module be called if the module is already in sys.modules?

Tags: python

[PEP302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#specification-part-1-the-importer-protocol) says that `load_module` must return entry in `sys.modules` if one already exists. That seems like an unnecessary burden, because the caller (i.e. Python's import system) *could* simply look in `sys.modules` before calling load_module, and notice that `load_module` has no real work to do (but it does not do that for some reason?).

If the idea is to notify the loader that an import is being attempted, seems like calling `my_loader.already_loaded(module)` (or another similar interface) would be better, because then, `load_module` can focus on it's "real" job, and not have to worry about whether the module is already in `sys.modules`.

Comment: Maybe ask this question on the python-dev mailing list?

Comment: Read the next sentence in PEP302 — "(Otherwise, the reload() builtin will not work correctly.)".

Comment: @martineau: that sentence does not explain. Read my question: the Python import system could (but does not) detect that such behavior is required and skip calling load_module entirely.